# Getting error while connecting sql server from linux using sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I'm getting an error while running following sqoop command from linux server to get list tables from SQL Server `TRANSHIST` database.

Command :

```
sqoop list-tables --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://10.171.7.132:1433;database=TRANSHIST' --username rugu.ram -P --verbose
```

Error message :

> 17/04/12 09:17:18 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
>   17/04/12 09:17:18 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
>   17/04/12 09:17:18 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
>   17/04/12 09:17:19 DEBUG oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop can be called by Sqoop!
>   17/04/12 09:17:19 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
>   17/04/12 09:17:19 DEBUG manager.DefaultManagerFactory: Trying with scheme: jdbc:sqlserver:
>   17/04/12 09:17:19 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
>   17/04/12 09:17:19 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Instantiated ConnManager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager@74455848
>   17/04/12 09:17:19 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.
>   17/04/12 09:17:20 ERROR manager.CatalogQueryManager: Failed to list databases

Comment: please share full error. I am sure there are more logs

Comment: Issue has been resolved by defining SQL server account ID instead of windows auth ID.